# cx_Freeze not working - no module named cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I've been trying to compile a game I'm writing with python into an exe with cx_Freeze so my friends can play it without the python interpreter. However, when I run the "build" command through cmd, I get an error saying "ImportError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'". I've done this every way in and out, changing the capital letters in "cx_Freeze". I'm trying to use 3.4.3/3.5.1, and I'm using cx_Freeze version 4.3.4.

Thanks in advance...

in answer to Loïc's comment: yes, it is installed.

Comment: Is the module currently installed?
Please try : `python3.4 -m pip install cx_Freeze`

Comment: Try to open python in the interactive mode (cmd -> python) and type `import cx_freeze`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: It successfully imports without any error.

Comment: There's a good chance you have more than one Python installation on your system.

Comment: Have you installed cx_Freeze on both 3.4.3 and 3.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year late but I ran into this issue as well. To solve the issue: I ran the cx_Freeze exe found here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Copy to the directory of the file to compile the following:

- re.py
- sre_compile.py
- sre_constants.py
- sre_parse.py

from *"...\Lib"*

and build: `python <nameFileToBuild>.py build`